# Is .NET Framework 4.5 and later are available on Embedded Compact 2013 and Windows 10 IoT core?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-embedded-compact, windows-10-iot-core

I have been creating applications on Windows CE with .NET Compact Framework 3.5 and as you might guess lots of features of .NET 4, 4.5 and later does not exist in compact (espacially XAML support).

Are those features available on Windows Embedded Compact 2013 and/or Windows 10 Iot Core?

Before down-voting consider that there are not enough resources on these topics on the internet. Best source of knowledge comes from experienced people.

Comment: Windows Embedded Compact 2013 has .NET Compact Framework 3.9, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee486593.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows Embedded Compact 2013 it is basically the same situation than with older Win CE versions. But you get a slightly updated .Net Compact Framework.

It is actually possible to use XAML on WinCE, Microsoft calls it Silverlight in older WinCE versions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee502198.aspx
The issue for you is that it is desinged to work with native code for performance reasons, if you like to use it with .Net CF you may want to have a look at:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2010/WEM309

For Windows IoT Core you can use "Universal Apps" they use XAML and the new ".Net Core" this should be more feature rich than then .NET CF and its supported on all new Windows Systems
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/12/04/introducing-net-core.aspx

Comment: Satisfactory. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Widnows 10 Iot Core supports "Universal Apps". These are made with XAML.

Comment: How about .NET framework version? Can we only use .NET Core on iot core?